# Search Row not exist in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anyone help me to write the query for below condition.

Table 1

```
        ID    Key
        1      A
        2      A
        4      C
        5      D
        6      A
```

Table 2

```
        ID     Key
         2      B
         3      B
         5      D
         6      A
```

These are the two tables

I want a query in which the ID, which is not exist in `Table1` corresponding to `Table2`, where deleted from table.

Example: `ID = 1` row was completely deleted from `Table1`, and in which key are not match were also deleted

Example: `ID = 2`, exists in both tables but key are not same so the complete row also delete from `Table1` not in `Table2`, I need a single query which is applicable to both condition

Thanks in advance

Comment: Provide DBMS (SQL-Server, MySQL, Oracle, etc.), desired result and what you have tried?

Comment: i write a query to search not exists ID 'Select ID From Table 1 Where ID Not In (Select ID From Table 2)'

Comment: you need to know who was deleted and who was changed?

Comment: 'Table 2' is master table i dont want to delete any row from this,,Only 'table 1' rows are deleted and changed

Comment: @aparnasharma check an answer, maybe It will help you to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to check if exists in following:

```
DELETE FROM Table1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
             SELECT 1
             FROM Table2 t2
             WHERE Table1.Id = t2.Id  
                  )
       OR EXISTS (
             SELECT 1
             FROM Table2 t2
             WHERE Table1.Id = t2.Id AND Table1.[Key] <> t2.[Key]
                  )
```

**OUTPUT**

```
ID  Key
5   D
6   A
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, [Key] 
FROM table1
EXCEPT
SELECT id, [Key] 
FROM table2
```